# Passing Data into an Array- Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, segue

I am looking to pass data through a text box, and into an array (Second View Controller), so it can be added to a pool of data and randomly chosen.

For instance, you would input your name (and/or another name) into the text field in the First VC and and it would go into an array that would tell them which color they are shown in the Second VC.

Essentially, I'm trying to pass the data to a variable (which will hold all the names inputed), and append the variable to the array, then click a button to generate and randomly pull from the array via arc4random. My problem is its not appending. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

VC 1:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func StartTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SecondViewControllerSegue", sender: self)


    }
    @IBOutlet weak var AddPlayerTextField: UITextField!



    @IBAction func AddTexttoArrayBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        if AddPlayerTextField.text == nil
        {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "SecondViewControllerSegue", sender: self)
    }
        func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            let SecondViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController2
            SecondViewController.myString = AddPlayerTextField.text!
```

VC 2:

import UIKit

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    var myString = String ()

    var TeamBuildingQuestions = [ "is Red", "is Blue", "is Green", "is Purple","is Teal","is Orange", "is Red", "is Grey", "is Pink"]

    var MasterTeamBuildingQuestionsArray = [ "Hello", "beep bop bbeep", "Boop", "Bap","Bospop","bob the builder"]


    @IBOutlet weak var DisplayArray: UILabel!


    @IBAction func NextQuestionBtn(_ sender: Any) {

        let RandomArrayNumber = Int (arc4random_uniform(UInt32(TeamBuildingQuestions.count)))
        let QuestionDisplayed = TeamBuildingQuestions[RandomArrayNumber]
        DisplayArray?.text = QuestionDisplayed
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.



        TeamBuildingQuestions.append(myString)


    }
```

Comment: Is this your actual code?  There are parentheses missing in `AddTexttoArrayBtn` (which should be `addTexTtoArrayBtn`), so `prepare(for segue:)` is not being called because it is inside `AddTexttoArrayBtn`

Comment: Why would you append your text in didRecieveMemoryWarning???

Comment: Yes it's the actual code, I had some mistakes in it, I'm still new so my apologies. Thanks for catching that for me.

Answer (score 0):

In VC2, Instead of didReceiveMemoryWarning, implement TeamBuildingQuestions.append(myString) in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Thanks so much for catching it, I'll input it and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bug:

```
 if AddPlayerTextField.text == nil{
}
```

should be

```
  if AddPlayerTextField.text != nil && AddPlayerTextField.text.count > 0{
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'm just changing everything right now, I'll update on how it goes.